# Let $m \geq 1$ be an integer. Evaluate $\int_R \frac{\sin t}{t}J_m(t)\,dt$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

Let $m \geq 1$ be an integer. Evaluate $\int_R \frac{\sin(t)}{t}J_m(t)\,dt$

$$\int_R \frac{\sin(t)}{t}J_m(t)\,dt=\int_R \hat{\chi_{{(-1,1)}}}(t)J_m(t) \,dt =\int_R \hat{\chi_{{(-1,1)}}}(t)J_m(t) \,dt  = c_mx^m \int_{-1}^1 \hat{\chi_{{(-1,1)}}}(t)e^{its}(1-x^2)^{m-\frac{1}{2}} \,dt$$

How do I contunie from here?

Comment: Is $R$ the real line here? Also, it's worth noting that $\sin(t)/t =\sqrt{\pi/2t}J_{1/2}(t)$ which may provide another approach.

Comment: @Semiclassical I suppose you're used to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes R is the real line

Comment: Quite, or to $\pm\infty$. @AlexR

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes I realized the same thing. Hence I updated the post.

Comment: NB $\chi_{S^0} = \chi_{\pm1}$... You probably want $\sigma_{S^0}$ (the surface measure of $\{\pm1\}$) and not the characteristic function.

Comment: This might sound silly but whats the difference?

Comment: Looking at this again, I'm still a bit unclear: are you integrating from $a$ to $b$ on a prescribed interval of $\mathbb{R}$, or from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: The problem has been edited the problem is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any integer $m>0$, the result is $0$.
In case $m=0$ the result is $\pi$

[image]